# Creating Rope Physics for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I want to create a bungee jumping-like game in Unity and therefore I need a rope physics. I especially need elastic ropes with capability to pull objects with velocity after a little extension. Do you know any place to start? Because I have no idea how to start such scripting.

I looked at Asset Store. There are some rope physic simulators, but I have to do it on my own, plus they are really expensive.

I already tried using Spring and/or Configurable Joints in Unity, but they did not give what I want.

**EDIT:** I am examining Jakobsen relaxation method right now. If you have any more methods to offer, or know deeps of the method, please feel free to help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example on the Unity Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3D_Physics_Based_Rope) of creating 3d Physics based ropes. This might take a bit of configuration to work how you need it too.

There is an [Asset on the Asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3223) that costs only $15. It might be a little too complex for what you are doing, however.

> The NEW QuickRopes 2 rope physics editing tool has been completely
>   re-written for ease of use in mind. This tool is a powerful new way to
>   generate and edit complex rope simulations. Use the built in spline
>   editor to form your ropes into endless shapes before you ever hit
>   play! Do you want to use cloth as your rope? Now you can with the new
>   Cloth mesh type!

And the from [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22550/how-do-you-make-ropes.html) question:

> If you want to make a physics rope, it will take several segments of
>   rigid bodies attached by Joints. Currently your best bet would be the
>   HingeJoint.
>
> I recently worked on a Unity-powered game where we had a
>   chain/rope-like string of objects that trailed behind the character
>   and that was the class we used to tie those rigid bodies together.
>
> I'm going to be honest, this is a pretty intricate task and there
>   isn't really an easy way to implement this - especially the
>   winding/unwinding functionality.
>
> My personal advice is this - fake it as best you can. Unless the
>   entire game is solely about the most realistic crane ever built, just
>   fake it.

Comment: I already looked at QuickRopes 2, but in the context of my project, I have to implement the physics by myself. I would love to give just $15 and get away with it. I have seen that question and answer, which gave me idea to use small capsules to create a chain with Configurable joints. However, they are acting weird even though I did my best. Also they are colliding with the character in some odd way. It stops the character when it hits him. So that's my motive to start building rope physics.